# Is it possible to retrieve values refering to a string of the same name?

Tags: java

I'm doing a bit of a side project at the moment, and was wondering if it's possible to retrieve values from variables refering only to a String which shares the same name.

```
i.e.

int x,y,z;

String sa [] = {"x","y","z"};

//then loop through sa, and get the values associated with each name and store them into a different
//container.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If they're instance or static variables, you *can* do this using reflection to get the fields - but it would usually be better to use a `Map<String, Integer>`.

If you can tell us more about what you're trying to achieve in your side project that would help, but generally if you want to *dynamically* associate keys with values, you should use a map. For example:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new Map<String, Integer>();

map.put("x", 10);
map.put("y", 20);
map.put("z", 30);

Integer z = map.get("z"); // z is now 30...
```

Comment: basically I'm trying to store all variable values, across various points(multiple times). I guess in a way, keeping check on how they transition as flow of control moves through certain pieces of logic.

Comment: @MeMoryLEAk99: It's probably worth having some sort of "dump" method to log all the state in the most appropriate way then. That's probably *not* a good case for using a map - just write the method by hand. Assuming it's a well-encapsulated class, you probably shouldn't have *too* many variables anyway.

Comment: It's to help me debug amateur level code more than anything. Even though I'm intermediate level, because I've helped out a few people in the past I'm officially 'The Code Guy'™ :P 
Most people that I help like cramming their main with all their program logic rather than seperating it into logical classes. Hence something like this, will help me get to grips with what they've written (or what they think they've written in some cases!)

Comment: ^^I do think I'm going to end up doing a dump method like you mentioned. Although I would like a more elegant & reusable solution, I don't think it's worth the time and effort at this stage. Maybe at a later date when my grasp of reflection is better. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible, through the Reflection API: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking whether it's possible to read `a` local variable having `"a"` string? No.

However if `a`, `b` and `c` are fields, you can use [reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect) to obtain their values.

Answer (score 0):

Sort of like:

```
int x = 4;
y = GetVariable("x");
System.out.println(y);
```

Output:
    4

No, it's not unfortunately. Java doesn't store it's variable names.

Maybe you could give us an example of what you are trying to do to see if there is a better solution.